# Use bit masking to store application enabled features into DB

Tags: java

I want to store a lot of application features into database. I want to use one table row for this, so I want to use bit masking to store the enabled features. I tried this:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
int database_value = 0; 

public int setFeatureBitmask(int value) {
    int bitmask = 0;
    bitmask |= value;       
    return bitmask;
}

public static Set<String> processFeature(Integer bitmask) {
    HashMap<String, Integer> newMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    return newMap.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> (e.getValue() & bitmask) == e.getValue()).map(e -> e.getKey())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
}

@BeforeAll
public void setupData() {
    System.out.println("Populating settings map");

    map.put("Type1", 1);
    map.put("Type2", 2);
    map.put("Type3", 4);
    map.put("Type4", 8);
    map.put("Type5", 16);
    map.put("Type6", 32);
    map.put("Type7", 64);
    map.put("Type8", 128);
    map.put("Type9", 256);
    map.put("Type10", 512);
    map.put("Type11", 1024);
    map.put("Type12", 2048);
    map.put("Type13", 4096);
    map.put("Type14", 8192);
    map.put("Type15", 16384);
    map.put("Type16", 32768);
    map.put("Type17", 65536);
    map.put("Type18", 131072);
    map.put("Type19", 262144);
}

@Test
public void writeData() {
    System.out.println("Converting Map using bitmasking");

    for(int i=0; i<map.size(); i++) {

        int number_value = map.get(i);                      
        int result = setFeatureBitmask(number_value);           
        database_value = database_value + result;
    }       
}

@AfterAll
public void databaseInsert() {
    System.out.println("Final resut to insert into Database " + database_value);

    System.out.println("Converting back values from database");

    // read here values from database_value variable and convert them into hash     
}
```

The first question is how to store the converted numbers as one big table value for example `15990793`? Should I combine all converted numbers into one big number?
And also after I convert them how to translate them again so that I can use them?

Is there any working example? I found many bit mask examples but nothing complete working like my case. It's totally unclear how to get the working result can you advice?

EDIT:

I tested this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.DEFAULT)
public class DatabaseFeaturesTest {

    int opts = 0;
    Map<Feature, Boolean> features = new HashMap<Feature, Boolean>();
    Map<Feature, Boolean> featureMaps = new HashMap<Feature, Boolean>();

    public void enableFeature(Feature feature) {
        opts = opts | feature.getValue(); // Or regular sum
    }

    public void disableFeature(Feature feature) {
        opts = opts & (~feature.getValue());
    }

    public boolean isFeatureEnabled(Feature feature) {
        return (opts & feature.getValue()) != 0;
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("Producing Features ");

        features.put(Feature.A, true);
        features.put(Feature.B, false);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("Converting Features for storage into Database");

        int opts = features.entrySet().stream().filter(Entry::getValue)
                .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey().getValue())
                .sum();

        System.out.println("produced value " + opts);
    }

    @Test
    public void thirdTest() {
        System.out.println("Reading from database ");

        Map<Feature, Boolean> featureMaps = 
                   Arrays.stream(Feature.values())
                         .collect(toMap(f -> f, 
                                        f -> (optsFromDatabase & f.getValue()) != 0,
                                        (v1, v2) -> v2,
                                        LinkedHashMap::new));
    }

    @Test
    public void fourthTest() {

        Boolean feature1 = featureMaps.get(Feature.A);
        Boolean feature2 = featureMaps.get(Feature.B);
        System.out.println("Reading from database Feature A " + feature1);
        System.out.println("Reading from database Feature A " + feature2);
    }
}

enum Feature {
    A("Type1", 1), // 1 << 0
    B("Type2", 2), // 1 << 1
    C("Type3", 4), // 1 << 2,
    F("Type6", 32); // 1 << 5

    private final String featureName;
    private final int value;

    private Feature(String featureName, int value) {
        this.featureName = featureName;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getFeatureName() {
        return featureName;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

But for toMap I get `The method toMap((<no type> f) -> {}, (<no type> f) -> {}, (<no type> v1, <no type> v2) -> {}, LinkedHashMap::new) is undefined for the type DatabaseFeaturesTest`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question/confusion is centering on here.  A bit mask is just a number, which however is interpreted as being a series of bits.  To answer questions against a bit mask in Java or SQL, you just need to use the bitwise operators, as you seem to already be doing in your code.  Maybe you can show us your proposed SQL table structure.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My goal is to use only one number for example 15990793 in order to understand is some feature enabled. For this I want to use bitwise operators.

Comment: @PeterPenzov, bit fields can be combined into a single number by simply adding them, same as using the OR bitwise operator.  Then to test a number for a specific bit you just AND the bit with the number, e.g. (0x06 & 0x02) == 0x02

Comment: That is what @TimBiegeleisen is telling you, one number represents `N` number of bits where `N = bytes * 8` and you simply mask off the bits you do not care about with the bitwise operators. I think you need to read up on what bit masking actually is, a single byte ( as unsigned int `0 - 255` ) represents `8` bits you need to go back and clarify what you problem is as the question is unclear because it is apparent you are confusing terminology and concepts in your question and your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a fan of using random constant to express feature.

First wrap your features to an enum:

```
public enum Feature {
     A("Type1", 1), // 1 << 0
     B("Type2", 2), // 1 << 1
     C("Type3", 4), // 1 << 2,
     ...
     F("Type6", 32); // 1 << 5

     private final String featureName;
     private final int value;

     // Constructor, getters/setters
}
```

Suppose you have variable `int opts = 0` to store your features combination.

Now to enable a feature you do:

```
public void enableFeature(Feature feature) {
    opts = opts | feature.getValue(); // Or regular sum
}
```

To disable a feature you do:

```
public void disableFeature(Feature feature) {
    opts = opts & (~feature.getValues());
}
```

To test if a feature is enable:

```
public boolean isFeatureEnabled(Feature feature) {
    return (opts & feature.getValue()) != 0;
}
```

To convert a `Map<Feature, Boolean> features` to a combination integer:

```
int opts = features.entrySet().stream().filter(Entry::getValue)
                   .mapToInt(e -> e.getKey().getValue())
                   .sum();
```

Now you store your `opts` to database as a regular integer.

To read it back:

```
final int optsFromDatabase = ....; // Read that combination value from DB

Map<Feature, Boolean> featureMaps = 
       Arrays.stream(Feature.values())
             .collect(toMap(f -> f, 
                            f -> (optsFromDatabase & f.getValue()) != 0,
                            (v1, v2) -> v2,
                            LinkedHashMap::new));
```

You will have your features state back like:

```
{A=true, B=false, C=false, D=true, E=false, F=false ...}
```

**Update**

To support many features (Eg ~100 features), you should stick with String.

Now, you should modify your `Feature` class abit:

```
public enum Feature {
     A("Type1", 0), // index 0 in bit string
     B("Type2", 1), // index 1 in bit String
     C("Type3", 2), // index 2 in bit String
     ...
     Z("TypeZ", 100); // index 100 in bit String

     private final String featureName;
     private final int index;
}
```

Now convert your `Map<Feature, Boolean>` to bit String:

```
public String convertToDatabaseValue() {
    return Arrays.stream(Feature.values()).map(f -> isFeatureEnabled(f) ? "1" : "0").collect(joining());
}

public Map<Feature, Boolean> initFromDatabaseValue(String bitString) {
    // Note that, bitString length should equals to your number of feature. Or you have to padding it
    char[] bitArray = bitString.toCharArray();
    return Arrays.stream(Feature.values())
            .collect(toMap(f -> f,
                    f -> bitArray[f.getIndex()] == '1',
                    (v1, v2) -> v2,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));
}
```

Comment: Can I ask one additional question how to make values verification?